# Is there any way to setup match score field in salesforce

Tags: formula, formula-field, matcher

I need to set up a match score between the email and web domain at the lead level.

Is there any way to set up a formula field at the lead level?

For Reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

You can implement this via the String class in apex:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_getLevenshteinDistance

```
trigger CalculateLevenshteinDistance on Domain__c (before insert, before update) {
    for (Domain__c domain : Trigger.new) {
        if(String.isBlank(domain.Field_A__c) || String.isBlank(domain.Field_B__c)){
           domain.Result_Field__c = null;
           continue;
        }
      
        // Calculate Levenshtein distance
        Integer distance = domain.Field_A__c.getLevenshteinDistance(domain.Field_B__c);
        
        // Store the result in Result_Field__c
        domain.Result_Field__c = distance;
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use the [Jaro-Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance), this CAN be done in a salesforce formula like so:

```
IF(
 ISBLANK(Field1__c) || ISBLANK(Field2__c),
 0,
 1 - (
   IF(
     LEN(Field1__c) > LEN(Field2__c),
     LEN(Field1__c) - LEN(Field2__c),
     LEN(Field2__c) - LEN(Field1__c)
   ) / LEN(Field1__c)
 )
)
```

The Jaro-Winkler distance is a string similarity measure that compares two strings and returns a value between 0 and 1, where 1 indicates a perfect match.